# Spark: StreamCorruptedException when deploying to OpenShift in cluster mode

Tags: java, apache-spark, openshift

I'm trying to submit a Spark application to my Spark master. The master and several slaves are running in an OpenShift-Environment. The web UI of the Spark master shows the connected workers.

The application jar is deployed to `/jars` in every spark pod.

This is my submit-script:

```
spark-submit2.cmd --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/jars" 
                  --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/jars" 
                  --conf "spark.submit.deployMode=cluster" 
                  --master spark://******:31824 
                  --class Main 'local:/jars/SparkHelloWorld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

The application itself is simple:

```
public class Main {

    private static String MASTER = "spark://******:31824";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Create a SparkContext to initialize
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster(MASTER)
                .setAppName("SparkPi");

        // Create a Java version of the Spark Context
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        final int slices = (args.length == 1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 4;
        final int n = 100000 * slices;
        final List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            l.add(i);
        }

        final JavaRDD<Integer> dataSet = sc.parallelize(l, slices);

        final int count = dataSet.map(integer -> {
            double x = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            double y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            return (x * x + y * y < 1) ? 1 : 0;
        }).reduce((a, b) -> a + b);

        System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n);
    }
}
```

Every time I run this script, i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$$anonfun$7.apply(Client.scala:233)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client$.main(Client.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 01000D31
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:857)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.<init>(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.<init>(JavaSerializer.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserializeStream(JavaSerializer.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:259)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:562)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:159)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:107)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:207)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:120)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I couldn't find this problem in any spark documentation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be related to a different Spark version in the master and in the slaves.

Comment: How to get the spark version of master and slaves

Comment: You can run `spark-submit --version` in each node.

Answer (score 5):

It may happen due to one of following :

1. Version of spark used in code is different than that of cluster.
2. Scala version mismatch of spark used for coding and used to run cluster.

In my case I was using Spark dependencies built with scala 2.10 while in cluster it was running on spark built with 2.11.
Hope it helps someone. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was due to version mismatch between `pyspark` which I installed using `pip` and my `spark`.